# Переключение на новое окно pywinauto

Tags: python, gui, pywinauto

автоматизирую одну программу. В начале когда я запускаю её там логин панель(вход), я нажимаю на кнопку войти дальше окно закрывается и через время появляется другое
Задача:

1. Дождаться появления нового окна
2. Переключиться на это окно что бы можно было с ним работать

Вот код:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import pywinauto.mouse as mouse

app = Application(backend="uia").start("Alien Crypter v3.exe")
windows = app.window(title="Alien Crypter", auto_id="Form2", control_type="Window").wait('visible', timeout=20, retry_interval=0.5)

def login(app):
    coords = app.Dialog.child_window(title="Login", auto_id="Guna2GradientTileButton1", control_type="Pane").rectangle().mid_point()
    mouse.click(coords=(coords.x, coords.y))
login(app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле много не понадобилось, достаточно просмотреть приложение например в `Instepct.exe` и найти например `auto_id` нужного элемента и дождаться его при помощи `wait()`

Comment: Ну, раз сами разобрались, можно и заакцептить ответ как валидный (серый чек бокс должен работать, даже если вы - автор вопроса).

Comment: Знаю) просто ограничение в 2 дня на пометку своего вопроса галочкой

Comment: О, про два дня не знал.)